# jQuery How do I know which of the input types I have increased the number of?

Tags: jquery

How can I understand which input increase my value, I couldn't print it in the console, thanks in advance.

```js
$(function(){
 $('.quantity').click(function(){
  let qty  = $('.qty').val();
  console.log(qty);
  });
});
```

```css
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {  
   opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quantity">1- Number <input type="number" class="qty" min="1" max="2"></div> 
<div class="quantity">2- Number <input type="number" class="qty" min="1" max="4"></div> 
<div class="quantity">3- Number <input type="number" class="qty" min="1" max="5"></div> 
<div class="quantity">4- Number <input type="number" class="qty" min="1" max="7"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might work out for you.
Just selecting the div with class:`quantity`
Later just filter the input type number with class `qty` inside the clicked div.

```js
$(function(){
 $('.quantity').click(function(){
  let qty  = $(this).find('.qty').val();
  console.log(qty);
  });
});
```

```css
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {  
   opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quantity">1- Number <input type="number" class="qty" min="1" max="2"></div> 
<div class="quantity">2- Number <input type="number" class="qty" min="1" max="4"></div> 
<div class="quantity">3- Number <input type="number" class="qty" min="1" max="5"></div> 
<div class="quantity">4- Number <input type="number" class="qty" min="1" max="7"></div>
```

Comment: Accepted after 4 minutes :D

Answer (score 1):

`$('.quantity')` selects all the divs with `class="quantity"`, you need either to use a .each() https://api.jquery.com/each/ to see all the diferents values of each input.
As well you need to select the `$(".qty")` of each using `$(this).children(".qty")`